# I want the answer to a question to appear on the screen for confirmation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We are using Material-UI in React to create a web form.

**In components / Content.js, case 3: I want to create a confirmation screen that displays the answer to the question below.**

I've done a lot of research, but I'm stuck in a situation where I don't know how to implement it.
Can anyone give me some advice?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Content from "./components/Content";

function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container direction="column">
      <Header />
      <div style={{ padding: 30 }}>
        <Content />
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**src / components  / contents.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import Stepper from "@mui/material/Stepper";
import Step from "@mui/material/Step";
import StepLabel from "@mui/material/StepLabel";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Radio from "@mui/material/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@mui/material/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@mui/material/FormLabel";
import Tooltip from "@mui/material/Tooltip";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";

function getSteps() {
  return ["お客様の情報を入力してください", "以下にお答えください", "ご相談ください", "以下の内容をご確認ください"];
}

function getStepContent(stepIndex) {
  switch (stepIndex) {
    case 0:
      return (
        <>
          {/* <DatePicker views={["year"]} label="Year only" value={selectedDate} onChange={handleDateChange} /> */}
          <div>
            <FormControl component="fieldset">
              <FormLabel component="legend">- 性別 -</FormLabel>
              <RadioGroup row aria-label="gender" name="row-radio-buttons-group">
                <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="男性" />
                <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="女性" />
              </RadioGroup>
            </FormControl>
          </div>
          <div>
            <FormLabel component="legend">- 生年月日 -</FormLabel>
            <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-native-select">year</InputLabel>
              <Select native defaultValue="" id="grouped-native-select" label="Grouping">
                <option aria-label="None" value="" />
                <optgroup label="year">
                  {Array.from(Array(2020), (_, num) => (
                    <option key={num} value={num + 1}>
                      {num + 1990}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </optgroup>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-native-select">month</InputLabel>
              <Select native defaultValue="" id="grouped-native-select" label="Grouping">
                <option aria-label="None" value="" />
                <optgroup label="month">
                  {Array.from(Array(12), (_, num) => (
                    <option key={num} value={num + 1}>
                      {num + 1}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </optgroup>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-native-select">day</InputLabel>
              <Select native defaultValue="" id="grouped-native-select" label="Grouping">
                <option aria-label="None" value="" />
                <optgroup label="day">
                  {Array.from(Array(31), (_, num) => (
                    <option key={num} value={num + 1}>
                      {num + 1}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </optgroup>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    case 1:
      return (
        <div>
          <FormControl component="fieldset">
            <FormLabel component="legend">現在、生命保険に加入されていますか？</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup row aria-label="gender" name="row-radio-buttons-group">
              <FormControlLabel value="yes" control={<Radio />} label="はい" />
              <FormControlLabel value="no" control={<Radio />} label="いいえ" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <FormLabel component="legend">
              現在、入院中ですか。また、3ヶ月以内に医師の診察・検査の結果、入院・手術をすすめられたことがありますか？
            </FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup row aria-label="gender" name="row-radio-buttons-group">
              <FormControlLabel value="yes" control={<Radio />} label="はい" />
              <FormControlLabel value="no" control={<Radio />} label="いいえ" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <FormLabel component="legend">
              過去、5年以内に病気やケガで手術を受けたことまたは継続して７日以上の入院をしたことはありますか？
            </FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup row aria-label="gender" name="row-radio-buttons-group">
              <FormControlLabel value="yes" control={<Radio />} label="はい" />
              <FormControlLabel value="no" control={<Radio />} label="いいえ" />
            </RadioGroup>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <Grid container>
          <Grid sm={2} />
          <Grid lg={8} sm={8} spacing={10}>
            <Tooltip title="ご相談内容を記入することができます" placement="top-start" arrow>
              <TextField
                label="ご相談内容"
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"
                rows={4}
                multiline
                variant="outlined"
                placeholder="その他ご要望等あれば、ご記入ください"
              />
            </Tooltip>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    case 3:
      return (
        <div>
          <FormControl component="fieldset">
            <FormLabel component="legend">- 性別 -</FormLabel>
            <FormLabel component="legend">- 生年月日 -</FormLabel>
            <FormLabel component="legend">現在、生命保険に加入されていますか？</FormLabel>
            <FormLabel component="legend">
              現在、入院中ですか。また、3ヶ月以内に医師の診察・検査の結果、入院・手術をすすめられたことがありますか？
            </FormLabel>
            <FormLabel component="legend">
              過去、5年以内に病気やケガで手術を受けたことまたは継続して７日以上の入院をしたことはありますか？
            </FormLabel>
            <FormLabel component="legend">ご相談内容</FormLabel>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    default:
      return "Unknown stepIndex";
  }
}

function Content() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const steps = getSteps();
  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };
  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };
  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid sm={2} />
      <Grid lg={8} sm={8} spacing={10}>
        <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel>
          {steps.map((label) => (
            <Step key={label}>
              <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
            </Step>
          ))}
        </Stepper>
        {activeStep === steps.length ? (
          <div>
            <Typography>全ステップの表示を完了</Typography>
            <Button onClick={handleReset}>リセット</Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Typography>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</Typography>
            <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={handleBack}>
              戻る
            </Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleNext}>
              {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "送信" : "次へ"}
            </Button>
          </div>
        )}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default Content;
```

Comment: It's not clear what the desired behavior should be. I see three questions in "case 3", and when your app runs this is shown at the last step. Do you want to show some sort of confirmation when the user clicks the 送信 button?